# Excel GoalSeek algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, excel

Does anyone have the code for this algorithm ? Any C-based programming language would be OK but I prefer C#.

I could try to implement it but I'm sure I'm not the first one...

**edit:** It's not homework, it's a "gimme teh codez" question :D I just don't want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GoalSeek most likely uses the [Bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method)

> The bisection method in mathematics is a root-finding method that
>   repeatedly bisects an interval and then selects a subinterval in which
>   a root must lie for further processing. It is a very simple and robust
>   method, but it is also relatively slow. Because of this, it is often
>   used to obtain a rough approximation to a solution which is then used
>   as a starting point for more rapidly converging methods.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) The method
>   is also called the interval halving method,[2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2007/12/17/bisection-based-xirr-implementation-in-c.aspx) the binary search
>   method,[3] or the dichotomy method.[4]

I found a C# implementation here : [Bisection-based XIRR implementation in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2007/12/17/bisection-based-xirr-implementation-in-c.aspx)

Comment: Link is dead. This live link is possibly the one you were referring to: https://www.lucabol.com/posts/2007-12-17-bisection-based-xirr-implementation-in-c/

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TridentGoalSeek/

Your algorithm needs to implement the IGoalSeekAlgorithm interface.
Then usage is as follows:

```
var myAlgorithm = new MyAlgorithm(90463.45M, 200);
var goalSeeker = new GoalSeek(myAlgorithm);
var seekResult = goalSeeker.SeekResult(96178.21M);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.nuget.org/packages/Budoom.GoalSeek/

Sample usage:

```
var sc = new SomeCalculation(); //implements interface Budoom.IGoalSeek

var goalSeek = new Budoom.GoalSeek(sc);
var goalSeekResult = goalSeek.TrySeek();
```

or use the static method and pass the calculation function to it, like this:

```
var goalSeekResult = Budoom.GoalSeek.TrySeek(Calculate);
```