# Invoke GoalSeek from C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an Excel file that I am reading and updating from my C# code. I want to retain the Excel template but update data therein from C# using the goal seek function. I do not want to replicate the goal seek algorithm in C# but only invoke that function in Excel file to update the data in the Excel file itself.

Is there a way that I may call the goal seek function in Excel from C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel GoalSeek algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284301/excel-goalseek-algorithm)

Comment: I do not want to create an algorithm in C#, only want to invoke the feature in excel so that it creates output in the excel sheet itself.

Comment: Did you try `get_Range(...).GoalSeek`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.irange.goalseek.aspx