# Excel Function Goal Seek Equivalent Algorithm in C #

Tags: c#

Before discussing my problem, I tell you the business context.

I need to automate a credit simulator now used in Excel, which uses the Goal Seek function to calculate the gross amount of credit.

The only thing I need to automate is the calculation of the gross amount, but to achieve that I need the Goal Seek function of Excel in C # or JS, that's why I turn to you to find an algorithm, library or code to solve this calculation.

Use TridentGoalSeek but you do not have much documentation on how to use this library.

Thank you in advance for your support.
Regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel GoalSeek algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284301/excel-goalseek-algorithm)

Comment: It is not the same function, since GoalSeek receives three input parameters and TridentSeek only one.

Answer (score 3):

Nuget has libraries available like Trident.GoalSeek and Budoom.GoalSeek.

Budoom.GoalSeek has an open source implementation available on [GitHub] (https://github.com/bayazidahmed/Budoom.GoalSeek/blob/master/README.md).

Sample usage and link to the nuget packages available at [Excel GoalSeek algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4284301/2351399)