# Is there any algorithm or function which can be used to implemen the Goal Seek functionality in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

The Goal Seek Excel function (often referred to as What-if-Analysis) is a method of solving for the desired output by changing an assumption that drives it. The function essentially uses a trial and error approach to back-solving the problem by plugging in guesses until it arrives at the answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't use unrelated tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284301/excel-goalseek-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple algorithms to solve this problem.

It is called multi dimension optimization.

There are group of probabilistic algorithms usually refereed as random search algorithms. Most famous is genetic optimization.

Also there is more classical approaches: Gradient descend, simplex method, etc.